# rails render model with location

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, render

I have a Picture model and i'd like to use `<%= render @pictures %>` in my view in order to display them.
I also want the pictures to be arranged as 3 columns across the screen.

If I use the `render` how can I know which picture I am rendering in order to know where to place it? (such as in a table or some other arrangement that is not 1 dimensional)

Is there a way to make the rendering automation to have a counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @pictures.each_index do |i| %>
    <% #some routine here %>
    <%= render @pictures[i] %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using each_with_index instead:

```
<% @pictures.each_with_index do |picture, i| %>
  <%= render picture, :i => i %>
<% end %>
```

Notice that you can pass index to the partial as well.